# No internet connection behind enterprise proxy

Tags: 12.10, networking, proxy, virtualization

Even though I can install stuff via `apt-get install`, I can't ping anything outside local network or access any site.

My wired network adapter is connected in Bridge mode and got an ip via dhcp already.

I've already configured my proxy settings as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/environment 
http_proxy="http://myproxy:8080/"
https_proxy="https://myproxy:8080/"
ftp_proxy="ftp://myproxy:8080/"
```

**Host:** Windows 7 x64
**Guest:** Ubuntu 12.10 32bits

Comment: If it's anything like the Enterprise networks I've helped set up, internet connectivity might be restricted by MAC address, and proxies from within the network won't be able to communicate with the outside world.  Traffic filters and what not.  Did you talk to your network administrators to see if you're allowed to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but after downloading chromium and configuring my proxy settings in its Change proxy settings... (which opens the Ubuntu's Network Settings), it worked. Although I'm still not able use ping from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here...

After configuring my proxy settings on the chromium settings `Change settings proxy...` it worked.